# How to set both www-data and me as owner?

Tags: command-line, 20.04, permissions, apache2, web-development

So I've been developing for quite some time now on ubuntu and what I did till now was for example when I want to upload something to my site via cms or form or whatever I would change owner of the website to `www-data` and when I am writing code and I wanna save I would change owner to me. Now that became really annoying and I have to go around it somehow. So I've tried to create a group add me and `www-data` as members first I did `chown username:group /path/to/folder` followed by `chmod -R g+w /path/to/folder`. When that did not work I did `chown www-data:group /path/to/folder` followed by the same `chmod -R g+w /path/to/folder`. And when that also did not work and I could not find anything else on internet I came here :P Help is really appreaciated , thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files can only have one owner.

You can have the directory with `775` permissions and files with `664`. From there you can either make `www-data` the group and your user the owner. Or you can make the `www-data` the owner and your user as the group.